# Update bool value in Parse for iOS

Tags: ios, boolean, updates

I am using Parse for iOS. https://www.parse.com/docs/downloads/ 
However, i have faced difficulties for updating the bool value at specified objectID as shown in this picture.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=8y4zt2&s=5

I can add new row by setting like this. But, now, I want to update the bool value at specified objectID. I would like to know how to do.

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
```

Comment: Did you fetch the `PFObject` and then try changing the bool and saving it? https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/fetch

Answer (score 7):

I have found a way to do.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"test"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:objectIDForReport];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject * reportStatus, NSError *error)        {
        if (!error) {
            // Found UserStats
            [reportStatus setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"report"];

            // Save
            [reportStatus saveInBackground];
        } else {
            // Did not find any UserStats for the current user
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```